# Problem involving counting about marbles

Tags: problem-solving

Five red cards and four blue cards are blaced in a bag, five cards are selected blind from the bag, what is the probablity that they are all red?

Comment: It is a good practice to show whatever work you have done so far, so people know how to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible ways to choose $5$ marbles out $5+4=9$ marbles $$\dbinom{5+4}{5}=\frac{9!}{5!4!}=126$$ Favorable ways?: only $1$. So, the probability is equal to $\frac{1}{126}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{5}{5+4}\times\frac{4}{4+4}\times\frac{3}{3+4}\times\frac{2}{2+4}\times\frac{1}{1+4}=\frac{1}{126}$